# position:relative breaking background-clip: text

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

I'm using `background-clip: text` on an element with some child `<p>` elements. I wanted to add some `:after` elements to the `<p>` tags and position then absolutely in order to cover up the text and do some animations, but when I set `position: relative` on the `<p>` tags, they disappear. I'm guessing it has something to do with the combination of `background-clip` and `color: transparent`. It's like it removes the ability to use `background-clip`. Is there a way to get this working?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-align: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.container.relative p {
  position: relative;
}

/* .container.relative p:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
} */
```

```html
<p>The text below is relative, and appears invisible</p>
<div class="container relative">
  <p>Some Relative</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<p>The text below is <strong>not</strong> relative and is visible</p>
<div class="container">
  <p>Some</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Rissk13/pa1v6gdr/1/

Comment: can you also describe the effect you want to achieve with the pseudo element? probably we can do it without pseudo element and position:relative

Comment: I'm basically looking to mimic this effect on the name text on this site: https://nrly.co/ He does do it a different way, and I could do something similar, but my first gut was to try it with pseudo elements since it would be easier to match the sizing, so my main question I guess is why it it breaking with background-clip?

Comment: It has something to do with the painting order but I don't have enough details to write an answer. It can also be a bug but I am convinced it's not. it's like position:relative isolates the text from the background you are setting on the container.

Comment: I can do this effect without pseudo element and without position:relative;

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I'm open to other solutions without pseudo elements or different than the site I posted. I guess I'll have to go with something different

Comment: chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1352821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea with more gradient where you don't need `position:relative`.

Hover to see the effect:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-align: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.container p {
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0% 100%;
  background-position:left;
  transition:1s;
}
.container p:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;

}
```

```html
<p>The text below is <strong>not</strong> relative and is visible</p>
<div class="container">
  <p>Some</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I wasn't able to translate the text like in the demo with this solution but I came up with another animation I like better.